# How to activate an ssh-account in Bash function in BATS test?

Tags: bash, unit-testing, ssh, bats-core

### Context

As part of a Bash script that is tested using the BATS, I noticed that my tests are not terminated when I run a function that activates an ssh-account.

### Code

The following function assumes a private and public ssh key pair exists in `/home/<username>/.ssh/`. If I run it manually using `source src/the_bash_script.sh && activate_ssh_account <my_git_username>`, it works and says `Identity added: /home/name/.ssh/<my_git_email>`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Activates/enables the ssh for 
activate_ssh_account() {
    git_username=$1
    eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/"$git_username"
}
```

However, when it is ran from the test with:

```
#!./test/libs/bats/bin/bats
load 'libs/bats-support/load'
load 'libs/bats-assert/load'
# https://github.com/bats-core/bats-file#Index-of-all-functions
load 'libs/bats-file/load'
# https://github.com/bats-core/bats-assert#usage
load 'assert_utils'

source src/the_bash_script.sh


@test "Check if ssh-account is activated after activating it." {
    activate_ssh_account "some_git_username"
    assert_equal "Something" "Something_else"
}
```

It hangs indefinitely.

### Question

How can I activate an ssh-account without causing the BATS tests to hang indefinitely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test hangs indefinitely because BATS waits for `ssh-agent` to terminate (which runs in the background once line `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` is executed). To be more specific, BATS waits for *file descriptor 3* to be closed (which is being held open by `ssh-agent`).

Thus, this can be solved by either implementing the [workaround mentioned in the documentation](https://bats-core.readthedocs.io/en/stable/writing-tests.html#file-descriptor-3-read-this-if-bats-hangs) or by killing `ssh-agent`.

---

**Workaround from documentation:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Activates/enables the ssh for 
activate_ssh_account() {
    git_username=$1
    eval "$(ssh-agent -s 3>&-)"
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/"$git_username"
}
```

This closes fd 3 for `ssh-agent` and BATS will no longer hang. Note that this leaves `ssh-agent` running in the background, even after BATS exits. It is unclear from your question if that is desired or not. If it's not, use the alternative below.

---

**Kill `ssh-agent`:**

Add a cleanup trap to `activate_ssh_account`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Activates/enables the ssh for 
activate_ssh_account() {
    trap "trap - RETURN; kill \$SSH_AGENT_PID" RETURN
    git_username=$1
    eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/"$git_username"
}
```

The trap is executed when the function exits and kills `ssh-agent` using the pid exported by `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` (i.e. variable `SSH_AGENT_PID`).

If you don't want to use a trap for some reason, this will also work:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Activates/enables the ssh for
activate_ssh_account() {
    git_username=$1
    eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    result=0
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/"$git_username" || result=$?
    kill $SSH_AGENT_PID
    return $result
}
```

Note that the `||` construct is necessary because BATS will stop executing the function's code once a command fails (i.e. without `||`, `kill` will not be executed if `ssh-add` fails).

---

As a side note, to actually test if `activate_ssh_account` succeeds or fails, you should use `assert_success` instead of `assert_equal` (unless there is more code that you omitted in your question).

Answer (score 1):

I never used BATS but by reading the doc I can say that there is a specific command for sharing common code. You may need to specify the full path though:

> **`load`: Share common code**
>
> You may want to share common code across multiple test files. Bats includes a convenient load command for sourcing a Bash source file relative to the location of the current test file. For example, if you have a Bats test in `test/foo.bats`, the command
>
> `load test_helper`
>
> will source the script test/test_helper.bash in your test file. This can be useful for sharing functions to set up your environment or load fixtures.

###### Option1:

Try replacing

```sh
source src/the_bash_script.sh
```

with

```sh
load '/full/path/to/src/the_bash_script.sh'
```

###### Option 2:

Try adding the sourcing in `@test`

```sh
@test "Check if ssh-account is activated after activating it." {
    source /full/path/to/src/the_bash_script.sh
    activate_ssh_account "some_git_username"
    assert_equal "Something" "Something_else"
}
```